# How to nest two serializers with same model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have two serializers with same model. I want to nest them.

Unfortunately this approach does not work:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['name', 'word_count']


class BetterBookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    book = BookSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'book')
```

Expected result:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "book": {
    "name": "book_name",
    "word_count": 123
  }
}
```

Comment: `does not work` - what happens?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [**`source=*`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) instead of **`many=True`** as

```
class BetterBookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    book = BookSerializer(source='*')

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'book')
```

**[From the doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)**,

> The value **`source='*'`** has a special meaning, and is used to indicate that the entire object should be passed through to the field. This can be useful for creating nested representations, or for fields which require access to the complete object in order to determine the output representation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for. Many thanks!

Comment: Simple Is Better Than Complex ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the desired output like this:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['name', 'word_count']

class BetterBookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    book = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
         model = Book
         fields = ('id', 'book')

    def get_book(self, obj):
         return BookSerializer(obj).data
```

**Small Update:**
Although my approach to solve your problem works just fine, the answer from @JPG mentioning `source='*'` option is a good way to go. In that way you can easily use the nested serializer when creating new object.

Comment: What about converting json data to validated_data?

Comment: What json you need to convert ?  You mean when you are creating new book ?

Comment: Yes, I need it to work both ways. When converting model object to json, and when creating new object from json.